# PyQGIS: subtracting two values and append ID to list

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I would like to subtract two values retrieved from qgs feature iterator objects and append the value of the feature id to a list depending on a condition.

I have two layers:

```
roadsLayer
pathsLayer
```

What I have so far returns an empty list:

```
evenList = []
azimuthRoadsIDX = roadsLayer.fieldNameIndex('azimuth')
azimuthPathsIDX = pathsLayer.fieldNameIndex('azimuth')
roads = roadsLayer.getFeatures()
paths = pathsLayer.getFeatures()
for feat in roads:
    for feature in paths:
        pathsAzimuth = feat.attributes()[azimuthRoadsIDX]
        roadsAzimuth = feature.attributes()[azimuthPathsIDX]
        if (roadsAzimuth - pathsAzimiuth == 90) or (roadsAzimuth - pathsAzimth == -270):
            evenList.append(feature.id())
```

I also know that these values exist through manual testing and based on the fact that they are perpendicular lines.

Don't know why, but this works:

```
for feat in roadsLayer.getFeatures():
    roadsAzimuth = feat.attributes()[azimuthRoadsIDX]
    for feature in pathsLayer.getFeatures():
        pathsAzimuth = feature.attributes()[azimuthPathsIDX]
        if (roadsAzimuth - pathsAzimiuth == 90) or (roadsAzimuth - pathsAzimth == -270):
            evenList.append(feature.id())
```

Comment: I think you are not defining `pathsAzimiuth`, but defining twice `roadsAzimuth`. That's why your calculations never meet the conditions.

Comment: @gcarrillo That was a typo, sorry. It wasn't working even without this typo. I now found my solution, but i still don't know why the first way didn't work and second way did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that with your first solution the result of `roadsLayer.getFeatures()` is an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) and not a list ( iterable ) as in `for feat in roadsLayer.getFeatures()` and  iterators can only be iterated over once, after which they are exhausted (look at [Loop Like A Native](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html), [Understanding Python Iterables and Iterators](http://www.shutupandship.com/2012/01/understanding-python-iterables-and.html) or
[Build a Basic Python Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator/24377#24377)).
When looping over a given iterator a second time in a for loop, no more elements are returned and that creates serious problems with nested iterators (not for single iterator)

Example with lists

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6,7,8,9]
for i in a:
   for j in b:
      print (i,j)
(1, 5) (1, 6) (1, 7) (1, 8) (1, 9) (2, 5) (2, 6) (2, 7) (2, 8) (2, 9) (3, 5) (3, 6) (3, 7) (3, 8) (3, 9) (4, 5) (4, 6) (4, 7) (4, 8) (4, 9)
```

With iterators

```
# convert the lists to iterarors
e = iter(a)
f = iter(b)
for i in e:
   for j in f:
      print (i, j), 
(1, 5) (1, 6) (1, 7) (1, 8) (1, 9)
```

The solution ? Convert your iterator to an iterable (list)

With an example

1) Lists

```
for feat in azimuthRoads.getFeatures():
   roadsAzimuth = feat.attributes()[azimuthRoadsIDX]
   for feature in azimuthPaths.getFeatures():
        pathsAzimuth = feature.attributes()[azimuthPathsIDX]
        if (roadsAzimuth - pathsAzimuth == 90) or (roadsAzimuth - pathsAzimuth == 270):
            print feat.id(), feature.id(), pathsAzimuth, roadsAzimuth 
0 2 80 170
3 0 10 100
4 6 110 200
```

2) Iterators:

```
roads = roadsLayer.getFeatures()
paths = pathsLayer.getFeatures()
for feat in roads:
    roadsAzimuth = feat.attributes()[azimuthRoadsIDX]
    for feature in paths:
        pathsAzimuth = feature.attributes()[azimuthPathsIDX]
        if (roadsAzimuth - pathsAzimuth == 90) or (roadsAzimuth - pathsAzimuth == 270):
           print feat.id(), feature.id(), pathsAzimuth, roadsAzimuth 

0 2 80 170
```

3) Conversion (iterator -> iterable)

```
    roads = list(roadsLayer.getFeatures())
    paths = list(pathsLayer.getFeatures())
    for feat in roads:
        roadsAzimuth = feat.attributes()[azimuthRoadsIDX]
        for feature in paths:
            pathsAzimuth = feature.attributes()[azimuthPathsIDX]
            if (roadsAzimuth - pathsAzimuth == 90) or (roadsAzimuth - pathsAzimuth == 270):
               print feat.id(), feature.id(), pathsAzimuth, roadsAzimuth 

0 2 80 170
3 0 10 100
4 6 110 200
```

If you want to further simplify (only one for loop), use the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) standard Python module

```
evenlist = []
for roads, paths in itertools.product(roadsLayer.getFeatures(),pathsLayer.getFeatures()):
    if (roads.attributes()[azimuthRoadsIDX] - paths.attributes()[azimuthPathsIDX] == 90) or (roads.attributes()[azimuthRoadsIDX] - paths.attributes()[azimuthPathsIDX]== 270):
       eventList.append(feature.id())
print evenList
[2, 0, 6]
```

And in one line with  [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
evenList = [paths.id() for roads, paths in itertools.product(roadsLayer.getFeatures(),pathsLayer.getFeatures()) if (roads.attributes()[azimuthRoadsIDX] - paths.attributes()[azimuthPathsIDX] == 90) or (roads.attributes()[azimuthRoadsIDX] - paths.attributes()[azimuthPathsIDX]== 270)]
print evenList
[2, 0, 6]
```